# Spring cloud - Refresh scope - Get runtime value of configuration property of a spring-bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

I'd like to expose the current value of the configuration property of a spring-bean using spring-actuator https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/htmlsingle/#env

`GET /actuator/env/{props}`

I have 2 services:

- Cloud config service
- Application service

The cloud config have 2 configurations are `maximum-upload-allow = 1M` and `file-type = png`

Application service load those configs from the cloud-config service

like:

```
@Configuration @Getter
public class ApplicationConfigurationProperty {
  @Value("${maximum-upload-allow}")
  private String maximumImageSize;
}

@Configuration  @RefreshScope  @Getter
public class FileConfigurationProperty {
  @Value("${file-type}")
  private String fileType;
}
```

- I can get my configuration as well via `GET /actuator/env/maximum-upload-allow` (1M)  and   `GET /actuator/env/file-type` (png)

Now when I update configuration value `maximum-upload-allow = 2M` and `file-type = jpg`

Then I do refresh-scope by call bus-refresh https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-bus/2.1.4.RELEASE/multi/multi__bus_endpoints.html

I'd like to see my configurations using spring-actuator are:

`GET /actuator/env/maximum-upload-allow` => 1M (because No refreshscope)

`GET /actuator/env/file-type` => jpg (I marked as refreshscope)

but actually, spring-actuator return both new values (2M and jpg)

Q: How I can get my runtime value of maximum-upload-allow is 1M (current value because of NO RefreshScope here?

--- Update

```
@Configuration @Setter @Getter @ConfigurationProperties
public class ApplicationConfigurationProperty {
  @Value("${maximum-upload-allow}")
  private String maximumImageSize;
}
```

This configuration value refreshed without @RefreshScope annotation

I think these is correct behaviours mention here https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-bus/2.1.4.RELEASE/multi/multi__bus_endpoints.html

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried delaying the cache refresh scope to higher interval 

management.endpoint.beans.cache.time-to-live=60s

If not then some more pointers can be located here 

https://gist.github.com/dsyer/a43fe5f74427b371519af68c5c4904c7

Comment: I would like to get my old value (maximum-upload-allow=1M) until I restart my application service. I don't want this config is refreshable

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution is to implement a new actuator endpoint which is load @RefreshScope and use Reflection to read bean's properties